# Week to week autocorrelation

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, autocorrelation

I am trying to compute the week to week autocorrelation in
hourly data.
The data is in the form of python data frame named df

```
| idx |date time           | value |  Day    | 
|-----|------------------- |-------|---------|
|  0  |2022-03-01 00:00:00 |    3  | Tuesday |
|  1  |2022-03-01 01:00:00 |    5  | Tuesday |
|  2  |2022-03-01 02:00:00 |    7  | Tuesday |
| ... |       ...          |  ...  | ...     |
| 168 |2022-03-08 00:00:00 |  6    | Tuesday |
```

I am confused on how to choose the lag if I want to compute the autocorrelation between:

- index 168: Tuesday at 12 am (2022-03-08 00:00:00) and index 1 Tuesday 12 am of previous week (2022-03-01 00:00:00)

The target is to compute the auto correlation of the rest of the data with the same concept that is the autocorrelation of each data point(hour of day) with the data point of the previous week(same week day same hour)

what I have done is the following but not sure if this is correct:

```
 plot_acf(df['value'], lag= 24*7)
```

and got this result that I didn't know how to interpret :

[image: Autocorrelation result]

Appreciate your help in validating the logic of choosing the lag and interpreting the result if my choice of lag was correct!

Thank you !

Comment: Hey, were you able to figure this out, I'm going through something similar problem, wanted to know if you've a solution.